# Unable to enable cache disk in Intel Rapid Storage Technology

Tags: windows, windows-10, dell, raid1, intel

Okay, this is driving nuts:

I have a Dell XPS 8910SE that was originally running Windows 10 Pro 1809.  The OS disk was using Intel Rapid Storage Technology for a RAID1 array, and an m.2 SATA SSD as a dedicated cache/acceleration disk.  This setup was working

After running into an OS issue, I needed to start from scratch, breaking the RAID and deleting the OS disk partition before installing Windows 10 Pro 1909.  After reinstalling IRST, I rebuilt the RAID1 Array, but I'm no longer getting the option to use the m.2 SATA SSD as a dedicated cache/acceleration disk, and I can't figure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

- Specs:

  - Computer: Dell XPS 8910SE
- BIOS Settings:

  - Version: 1.1.10 (latest version on Dell support site)
  - SATA Operation: RAID On
  - Boot Mode: UEFI
  - Secure Boot Control: Enabled
  - Load Legacy OPROM: Disabled
- IRST Version: 16.8.3.1003 (Lastest version on Dell support site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to changes in the version of the IRST software.  Downgrading back to version 14 resolved my issue.